# Create span<span<T>> from vector<vector<T>>

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an `std::span<std::span<T>>` from a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` without doing any allocation, but I am not having success.

I have tried creating first a `std::vector<std::span<T>>`, but this of course requires allocating for the std::vector.

I have also tried creating first a `std::span<std::vector<T>>`, but then I am stuck on how to create the "internal" spans

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> vv; 
std::span<std::vector<T>> sv(vv);
std::span<std::span<T>> ss ??
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. A `std::span` is a non-owning view into existing data. But your outer `std::span` does not have such data to form a view into. You can create a `std::vector<std::span<T>>`.

Comment: I guess I somehow need to store the internal spans to be able to create a span of them, which means creating the vector. Probably better to use std::span<std::vector<T>> then

Comment: You could linearize your `vector<vector<T>>` to a `vector<T>`, then construct a `vector<span<T>>` whose elements point into sections of the linearized vector and that you use in place of occurrences of `vector<vector<T>>`. From this `vector<span<T>>` you can easily create a `span<span<T>>`.

Comment: @j6t well, the first step is not necessary at all. you can already create `vector<span<T>>` from `vector<vector<T>>` (which would do allocation).

Comment: @appleapple The idea is to not have a `vector<vector<T>>` in the first place.

Comment: @j6t which may be a possible change depend on context, but it's not the question, nor it solve the question in any way.

Comment: May I ask *why* are you trying to do that? Knowing the actual use case might lead to a better approach.

Comment: @Bob__ I'd say it's a reasonable thought (at least at first thought), like convert `vector<Derived*>` to `vector<Base*>` .

Comment: @appleapple Sure, but *maybe* what the OP really needs is a range of ranges, hard to say without any context.

Comment: @j6t I have a vector of vector because this comes from a list[list] in python. Not really a use case, its more a theorical question, since I can just pass a const ref to the vec<vec<>> in my code and that would work

Comment: To have it without any allocation you can make `std::ranges::view` over `vv` via `transform`. But I am not sure whenever it makes anything simpler, depends on the needs. https://godbolt.org/z/of9v9Whzs

Comment: @R2RT actually that is smart. The only problem is that if you want to receive that range of ranges in a function, you have to type a complex type or use a template

Comment: With helper concept function declaration does not look this bad: `void print(spans_range<int> auto spans)`  https://godbolt.org/z/T8vb6jfMn

Comment: @jjcasmar well you probably better directly use `vector<vector>` it's still a range of range, no transform needed (unless you somehow need the inner type to be exactly `span` but not the out).